# Creating Foreign keys from Visual Studio 2013 is very hard

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have installed visual studio 2013 express , and I want to create a new database table, and when I try to specify a FK relationship , I can not find a way to select from the table columns, instead I have to modify the DB script manually to specify the parent table name and the parent table key as follow:-

[image]
So is there a better way to create FKs from visual studio , same as when using sql server management studio ?
I remember on visual studio 2010 I use to create FKs very easy , by having the ability to select the parent table name and the parent table columns, similar to sql server management studio . so why i can not do the same on VS 2013 express ?
Thanks

Comment: Most people find that, after they've gotten used to writing it as plain SQL, doing this work via the GUI tools is slower and more awkward - might be worth considering. It also tends to make your skills more portable - quite a lot of this SQL follows the ANSI standard and so is usable on other database systems as well.

Comment: so you mean that there is no UI features inside VS 2013 to manage FK ?

Comment: There probably are, but I'm not aware of them personally. I haven't used any of the designers (within either VS or SSMS) for probably at least 10 years.